# Context setup is not updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Context always stumps me.  I am hoping the new Context API would help, but so far, still stuck.  I can get the initial value to appear, but the updates based on my Effect do not update the Component with the `useContext` value.  What am I doing wrong?

It's overkill to "need" context here, but I am wanting to have a context API that gives the value of the window scroll position, just to test out how the Context Provider/Consumer interacts with children:

context.js

```
import React, { useState, FC, useEffect } from "react";

interface IInitialContext {
  scrollY: number;
  // do to - implement removeEventListener function
}
const intialContext = {
  scrollY: window.scrollY,
  // removeEventListener: () => {},
};

const ScrollContext = React.createContext<IInitialContext>(intialContext);

const VerticalScrollContextProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [scrollY, setScrollY] = useState(intialContext.scrollY);
  // correctly logs scrollY

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener(
      "scroll",
      debounce(() => setScrollY(window.scrollY), 100) // correctly captures new scrollY position
    );

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", debounce)
  }, [scrollY]); // re-add listener when scrollY changes

  return (
    <ScrollContext.Provider value={{ scrollY }}> //i don't really need the value passed to component
      {children}
    </ScrollContext.Provider>
  );
};

function useScrollState() {
  const context = React.useContext(ScrollContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error(
      "useScrollState must be used within a VerticalScrollContextProvider"
    );
  }
  return context; // correctly tracks initial state 
}

export { VerticalScrollContextProvider, useScrollState };
```

and my component:

```
const Home = () => {
  const { scrollY } = useScrollState();
  // correctly has value on app first loading, does not receive updates.
  const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked button");
  };
  return (
    <VerticalScrollContextProvider>
      <StyledHome>
        <div id="text-wrapper">
          <StyledFirstName>Phil</StyledFirstName>
          <StyledLastName>Lucks</StyledLastName>
        </div>
        <Button text="clicker" onClick={handleClick} />
      </StyledHome>
    </VerticalScrollContextProvider>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

i appreciate any insight.

Comment: How are you updating the initial `scrollY` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For context to work, the component should be inside a provider.**

**From the docs of [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)**

> Accepts a context object (the value returned from React.createContext)
>   and returns the current context value for that context. The current
>   context value is determined by the value prop of the nearest
>    above the calling component in the tree.
>
> When the nearest  above the component updates,
>   this Hook will trigger a rerender with the latest context value passed
>   to that MyContext provider.

Now watch closely at the `<Home />` component.

```
const Home = () => {
  const { scrollY } = useScrollState();
  // correctly has value on app first loading, does not receive updates.
  const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked button");
  };
  return (
    <VerticalScrollContextProvider>
      <StyledHome>
        <div id="text-wrapper">
          <StyledFirstName>Phil</StyledFirstName>
          <StyledLastName>Lucks</StyledLastName>
        </div>
        <Button text="clicker" onClick={handleClick} />
      </StyledHome>
    </VerticalScrollContextProvider>
  );
};
```

This line which we are interested in is `const { scrollY } = useScrollState();` which tries to derive the `context` from parent `Provider`

**But, Is the  `<Home />` Component  inside a `<Provider />` ?**

**No. The `<Provider />` is inside the `<Home />` Component**

Run the below snippet and watch the console log to see which component runs first.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const intialContext = {
  scrollY: window.scrollY,
};

const ScrollContext = React.createContext(intialContext);

const VerticalScrollContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [scrollY, setScrollY] = React.useState(intialContext.scrollY);
  // correctly logs scrollY
  console.log("Rendering context");

  useEffect(() => {
    const eventListener = () => setScrollY(window.scrollY);
    window.addEventListener(
      "scroll",
       eventListener// correctly captures new scrollY position
    );

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", eventListener)
  }, [scrollY]); // re-add listener when scrollY changes

  return (
    <ScrollContext.Provider value={{ scrollY }}>
      {children}
    </ScrollContext.Provider>
  );
};

function useScrollState() {
  const context = React.useContext(ScrollContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error(
      "useScrollState must be used within a VerticalScrollContextProvider"
    );
  }
  return context; // correctly tracks initial state 
}





const Home = () => {
  const { scrollY } = useScrollState();
  console.log("Rendering Home");
  // correctly has value on app first loading, does not receive updates.
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked button");
  };
  return (
    <VerticalScrollContextProvider>
        <div id="text-wrapper">
          <h3>Phil</h3>
          <h3>Lucks</h3>
        </div>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Button</button>
        <h2>Scroll and see the console logs</h2>
    </VerticalScrollContextProvider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
#root {
height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

**And the solution** ...

Wrap the `Home` component inside the `Provider`

```
import React from "react";
import {VerticalScrollContextProvider, useScrollState} from "./context";

const Home = () => {
  const { scrollY } = useScrollState();
  // correctly has value on app first loading, does not receive updates.
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked button");
  };
  return (
      <div>
        <div id="text-wrapper">
          <h3>Phil</h3>
          <h3>Lucks</h3>
          {scrollY}
        </div>
        <button text="clicker" onClick={handleClick} />
      </div>
  );
};

export default () => (
  <VerticalScrollContextProvider><Home /></VerticalScrollContextProvider>
);
```

Run the snippet below and scroll to see the console logs.

```js
const {
  useState,
  useEffect
} = React;

const intialContext = {
  scrollY: window.scrollY,
};

const ScrollContext = React.createContext(intialContext);

const VerticalScrollContextProvider = ({
  children
}) => {
  const [scrollY, setScrollY] = React.useState(intialContext.scrollY);
  // correctly logs scrollY
  console.log("Rendering context");

  useEffect(() => {
    const eventListener = () => setScrollY(window.scrollY);
    window.addEventListener(
      "scroll",
      eventListener // correctly captures new scrollY position
    );

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", eventListener)
  }, [scrollY]); // re-add listener when scrollY changes

  return ( <
    ScrollContext.Provider value = {
      {
        scrollY
      }
    } > {
      children
    } <
    /ScrollContext.Provider>
  );
};

function useScrollState() {
  const context = React.useContext(ScrollContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error(
      "useScrollState must be used within a VerticalScrollContextProvider"
    );
  }
  return context; // correctly tracks initial state 
}





const Home = () => {
  const {
    scrollY
  } = useScrollState();
  console.log("Rendering Home", scrollY);
  // correctly has value on app first loading, does not receive updates.
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked button");
  };
  return ( <
    React.Fragment >
    <
    div id = "text-wrapper" >
    <
    h3 > Phil < /h3> <
    h3 > Lucks < /h3> <
    /div> <
    button onClick = {
      handleClick
    } > Button < /button> <
    h2 > Scroll and see the console logs < /h2> <
    /React.Fragment>
  );
};

const HomeWithProvider = () => {
  return <VerticalScrollContextProvider >
    <
    Home / >
    <
    /VerticalScrollContextProvider>
}

ReactDOM.render( < HomeWithProvider / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
#root {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: of course! it makes total sense about the provider wrapping the component itself.  ‍♂️THANK YOU!  
I will review this when outside of work hours some more and hopefully mark this as answered

Comment: No problem. Take your time 

Comment: marked as answer.  Thanks @Nithin Thampi.  
if I wanted to have a function available that "stops" the scroll event, would I expose that as part of the Provider like 
return (
    <ScrollContext.Provider value={{ scrollY, ADDNEWCALLBACKHERE }}>
      {children}
    </ScrollContext.Provider>
  );